# How do I use randomTrips.py correctly

Tags: sumo

I have a .net.xml file and I want to get a trips.xml file using randomTrips.py, but mine doesn't work. I have a Windows 10 64-bit computer. My commands on Command Prompt are:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\tools>randomTrips.py --help`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\tools>python randomTrips.py --help`
and

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\tools>py randomTrips.py --help`.

If I run any of these commands, I will get the following result:

```
[Blank Line]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\tools>
```

I have reinstalled SUMO using a different installer and using the installer Repair function. Also, I do not get the trips.xml file I want. If you know how to solve the problem, please give me some pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you added SUMO_HOME to environment variables.

This command should work:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\tools>python randomTrips.py --help
```

The result I got:

```
user@pc MINGW64 /c/Program Files (x86)/Eclipse/Sumo/tools
$ python randomTrips.py --help
usage: randomTrips.py [-h] [-c FILE] [-C FILE] [--save-template FILE]
```

Could you check your Python version and SUMO version?

```
$ sumo --version
Eclipse SUMO sumo Version 1.9.0

$ python --version
Python 3.9.5
```